# Request header field content-type is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response

Tags: node.js, reactjs, aws-api-gateway

I'm getting this error after the preflight request:

*Access to fetch at 'myInvokeUrl' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: Request header field content-type is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response.*

My goal is to fetch a POST request to API Gateway. I added the Access-Control-Allow-Headers header to my OPTIONS response in the Gateway console with a value of 'Content-Type,X-Amz-Date,Authorization,X-Api-Key,X-Amz-Security-Token', but the actual response doesn't have this field at all.

Response Headers:

```
access-control-allow-methods: POST,OPTIONS
access-control-allow-origin: *
content-length: 36
content-type: application/json
date: Mon, 28 Oct 2019 21:13:22 GMT
status: 200
```

My Lambda function (it's working if I test it in API Gateway):

```
module.exports.sendM = function (event, context, callback) {
console.log(event);
var body =`<p>Olá, ${event.name}!</p><p>Esse é o resumo do seu pedido: </p>`;

let minion1 = event.minion;
let minion2 = event.minion2;
let minion3 = event.minion3;

if (event.minion1){
    body += `<p> Au Naturel: ${event.minion1}</p>`;
}
 if (event.minion2){
    body += `<p> Phil: ${event.minion2}</p>`;
}
 if (event.minion3){
    body += `<p> Bored Silly Kevin: ${event.minion3}</p>`;
}
body += `<p> Enviar para ${event.address}</p>`;

var mailOptions = {
    from: 'leosole@gmail.com',
    subject: 'Pedido minionshop',
    html: body,
    to: `${event.mail}`
    // bcc: Any BCC address you want here in an array,
};


// create Nodemailer SES transporter
var transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
    SES: ses
});
const response = {
    statusCode: 200,
    headers: {
      "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*", // Required for CORS support to work
      "Access-Control-Allow-Credentials": true, // Required for cookies, authorization headers with HTTPS
      "Access-Control-Allow-Headers": "Origin,Content-Type,X-Amz-Date,Authorization,X-Api-Key,X-Amz-Security-Token",
      "Access-Control-Allow-Methods": "POST, OPTIONS"
    },
    body: JSON.stringify(event)
};
// send email
console.log(event.mail);
transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, function (err, info) {
    if (err) {
        console.log("Error sending email");
        callback(err);
    } else {
        console.log("Email sent successfully");
        callback(null, response);
    }
});};
```

The request:

```
handleSubmit = event => {
event.preventDefault();
console.log('trying to fetch')
fetch('myInvokeUrl', {
  method: 'POST',
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    // 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*'
  },
  body: JSON.stringify({
    name: this.state.name,
    mail: this.state.mail,
    address: this.state.address,
    minion1: this.state.minion1,
    minion2: this.state.minion2,
    minion3: this.state.minion3
  })
})
.then(function(response) {
return response.json()
}).then(function(json) {
  console.log('parsed json', json)
}).catch(function(ex) {
  console.log('parsing failed', ex)
})}
```

[My integration response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xibIO.png)

Comment: how does your CORS configuration(https://docs.aws.amazon.com/en_pv/apigateway/latest/developerguide/how-to-cors.html) at AWS look like?

Comment: I'm not sure what is that. Is it the integration response? https://i.stack.imgur.com/xibIO.png

Answer (score 1):

Navigate to your *Method Response* **post** method (not **options**) and check if you have these configurations:

[image]

Then navigate to your *Integration Response* **post** method (not **options**) and check if you have these configurations:

[image]

Try it first without the **send email** function, just `callback(null, { response });` before **send email**;

Why?

**send email** could cause *Internal server error (500)* meaning you will have to add another *HTTP Status* to your both **POST**,**OPTIONS** *Integration Response* methods.

Hope that help

Comment: My POST method have these configurations.
I tried without the sendMail function, but it still gives me the same error.

Comment: Did you redeploy your api after enabling CORS?

Comment: I did. I'll try using axios to see if the problem persists.